# Changing meta-tags dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with several paragraphs, when a user clicks on the 'snapshot' button beside a paragraph, the paragraph is reproduced on a canvas as an image and displayed above the original paragraph.

Beside the snapshot paragaph is a 'share' button, how do I change the url of the following meta-tag content to the url of the snapshot paragraph on the click of the 'share' button.

**share button**

```
<a href="#" id="share">Share?</a>
```

**BEFORE SHARE BUTTON CLICK**

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="p.jpg">
```

**AFTER SHARE BUTTON CLICK**

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="image/paragraphxi34343.jpg">
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Unless things have changed since i've last dealt with this (few years ago,) changing that dynamically will have no affect because facebook will request the page separately, thus getting the original value rather than the one you change it to. I hope i'm wrong though, as that would mean SPA sites would have a real problem with share buttons.

Comment: Hey Kevin, what about Twitter?

Comment: Not sure, never really messed with it. Testing would be easy, change the tag through the browser console and try it.

Comment: It works, but obviously users aren't going to open their consoles ;p  Any solutions on how it can be programmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is optimized way to do it, but this should work.

```
$("meta").each(function() {

  if($(this).attr("name") == "twitter:image") {
    $(this).attr("content" , "image/paragraphxi34343.jpg");
  };
});
```

A more generic way would be

```
function changeMetaContent(metaName, newMetaContent) {
    $("meta").each(function() {

      if($(this).attr("name") == metaName) {
        $(this).attr("content" , newMetaContent);
      };
    });
}
```

Call like

```
changeMetaContent("twitter:image", "image/paragraphxi34343.jpg");
```

**Updated after discussion in comments**

If you have the url in an input field do this.

```
<input value="http://some-image-url.png" type="hidden" id="image-url-input" />
```

Call the function like this;

```
var imageURL = $("image-url-input").val();
changeMetaContent( "twitter:image", imageURL );
```

Comment: Hey Kiranvj, the problem is that the several paragraphs are dynamic and anyone of them can be selected so how do we instead get the current image url of the selected/'snapshot' paragraph?

Comment: You don't have the image url, you only have the raw image data in canvas. If you need url , you need to send this raw image data from canvas to your server and store it as a image with some filename, then only you can get a image url.

Comment: Hey Kiranvj, I found a way to store the canvas image data and return a url of the image to the client side(an input form). How can I use the returned url in the context of your code? Or better yet, how can I return the url through Ajax/PHP into the  `var newmetaContent` and update the page for use? You're busy so take your time @kiranvj

Comment: @SteveGates Where do you have the image URL now, in PHP or in the client side in a input field?

Comment: client side in an input field

Comment: Man, you're awesome Kiranvj, thank you for not ignoring me and taking time to help out. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('head meta[name=twitter:image]').attr('content', 'image/paragraphxi34343.jpg');
```

Take a look at : https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the escaping for the colon.     


$('head meta[name=twitter\\:image]').attr('content', 'image/paragraphxi34343.jpg');